# Counting the number of rows by year with a DateTime Index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a DataFrame which has a DateTime index as such

[image]

What I would like to do would be to find how many rows/instances occur by year. E.g. how many instances
occur in the year 2013, 2014 ... 2020.

I would like to return this as a series or dataframe which I can then use to plot to show how many instances there were per year e.g.

```
2013 20
2014 14
.
.
.
2020 25
```

Is there a way to use the groupby or another function on the datetime index to return the counts of how many rows there are per year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with a callable:

```
df.groupby(lambda x: x.year).size()
```

When you use `groupby` this way, the callable works directly with the indices.

This is equivalent to:

```
def func(date):
    return date.year

df.groupby(func).size()
```

Since you're working with [`pandas.Timestamp`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html) you can easily access to the `year` attribute.

Comment: That did exactly what I was looking for it to do. Could you please give a brief explanation of how the variable x is able to return x.year?

Comment: @TimWilliams Nice! do you know about lambda functions?

Comment: I have learned about them briefly, I will check the documentation. Thank you for your explanation as it was very helpful.